# How to select every other character in a string after the first Python

Tags: python, string, slice

For a school project I have been trying to make a very very simple encryptor, however I am struggling with the encryption part. Basically I would like to have the encryption be every other letter starting from the first at the beginning and every other character at the end.

So 123456 would return as 135246

I am having trouble selecting every other letter after the first

```
def encrypt(message):
    return "%s%s" % (message[::-1],message[::2])

print(encrypt("123456"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use following code

```
def encrypt(message):
   return "%s%s" % (message[::2],message[1::2])
```

Answer (score 2):

You could tweak your method a little as follows:

```
def encrypt(message):
    return "%s%s" % (message[::2],message[1::2])

print(encrypt("123456")) # 135246
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `slicing` and `indexing`

```
msg = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
In [30]: msg[::2] + msg[1::2]
Out[30]: [1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6]
```

and for your function

```
def encrypt(message):
    return "%s%s" % (message[::2],message[1::2])

print(encrypt("123456"))
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `message[::-1]` you are actually commanding to display all the values in reverse. 
So expected output for  `message[::-1]` will be **654321**

So use

```
(message[::2],message[1::2])
```

This should work like a charm.